# How can I find the name of the process of an app running in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, bash

TL;DR I need to find the name of the process being run by any app I have open. I need to input this into ps h -C to, at any time, see if the app is running.

I have a bash script written that opens an app, but only if it's not already running. It is extremely simple, so here is the whole thing.

~/.config/runifnotrunning.sh

```
if (( $(ps h -C $2 | wc -l) == 0 )); then
    exec $1
fi
```

The code below is the bit of code that I am struggling with.

```
$(ps h -C $2 | wc -l)
```

It returns 0 when the process isn't running and something else when the process is running.

For an app like Brave, I can run

```
./runifnotrunning.sh brave brave
```

because the name of the process and the command to run brave are the same. The issue I'm having is when I don't know the name of the process. IntelliJ IDEA (installed with JetBrains Toolbox), for example, is run with

```
exec "~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/201.7846.76/bin/idea.sh" %f
```

But what do I put inside $(ps h -C $2 | wc -l)?

I would like to know how I can find the name of the process to put in that code for any of my apps.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello

> Keep it simple and platform independent. A very oldschool way for
> checking if a programm name is already loaded and running comes with
> pidof. Example...

```
if (pidof ${1})
then
 (echo "Result: ${?} - ${1} running";echo "Fail Code";return 1)
else
 (echo "Result: ${?} - ${1} not running";echo "Start Code";return 0)
fi
```

> ...and pidof is seen often on embedded linux devices.

Comment: Yes but my question still remains. How can I find the name of the program to input into pidof? if I do pidof webstorm while webstorm is running, it will still return 0 correct? Because this is not the official name of the process running. I need that name before I can enter it.

Comment: I just checked to confirm that pidof webstorm doesn't produce a number even if I have webstorm open. I will most likely switch to your suggested method of checking because it is simple and platform-independent, so thank you for your response, but I still need to know the name of the running process.

Comment: A running process has an PID.

Comment: I checked and the PID is not what I am looking for. It's a number which is not what I need. I need the name of the process. In order to even get the paid I already need to know the processes name.

Comment: Then look in /proc. The PID is a folder. Inside the PID folder is a named link called "exe". The target of "exe" is the full path to "name". ```(for i in $(echo -ne $(pidof ${1}));do ls -Flap /proc/$i/exe;done)```